Selenium running with an error, the browser matches the chromedriver version, and the system variables are configured, but the error is still reported
from selenium import webdriver
driver = webdriver.Chrome()

error:
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\Admin\Desktop\exec\selenium1.py", line 3, in <module>
    driver = webdriver.Chrome()
  File "D:\software_test\PYTHON\lib\site-packages\selenium\webdriver\chrome\webdriver.py", line 45, in __init__
    super().__init__(
  File "D:\software_test\PYTHON\lib\site-packages\selenium\webdriver\chromium\webdriver.py", line 66, in __init__
    super().__init__(command_executor=executor, options=options)
  File "D:\software_test\PYTHON\lib\site-packages\selenium\webdriver\remote\webdriver.py", line 208, in __init__
    self.start_session(capabilities)
  File "D:\software_test\PYTHON\lib\site-packages\selenium\webdriver\remote\webdriver.py", line 292, in start_session
    response = self.execute(Command.NEW_SESSION, caps)["value"]
  File "D:\software_test\PYTHON\lib\site-packages\selenium\webdriver\remote\webdriver.py", line 347, in execute
    self.error_handler.check_response(response)
  File "D:\software_test\PYTHON\lib\site-packages\selenium\webdriver\remote\errorhandler.py", line 193, in check_response
    raise exception_class(value)
selenium.common.exceptions.WebDriverException: Message: 

Thanks a lot!

Match the browser and driver version
Configure environment variables


What version of Selenium are you using?

selenium 4.20.0
